# Computing the $n$-th derivative at zero.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $k, N \in \mathbb{N}$. Define 
$$
H(x) = \int_{ax}^{bx} x^ke^{-c^2t^2}\mathrm{d}t = x^k \int_{ax}^{bx} e^{-c^2t^2}\mathrm{d}t
$$
I want to find a formula for $H^{(N)}(0)$. Here's what I've tried so far. We know:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
and so
$$
e^{-c^2x^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{c^{2n} x^{2n}}{n!}.
$$
Thus
$$
H(x) = x^k \int_{ax}^{bx} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{c^{2n} t^{2n}}{n!}\mathrm{d}t = x^k\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nc^{2n}}{n!} \int_{ax}^{bx} t^{2n}\mathrm{d}t.
$$

And this is where I am. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any guidance is appreciated! PS I am a first-year, and so I am limited to the methods covered (typically) in first-year. Thank you.